# How to display tree structure angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have object somethig like this:

```
{
 id: 1,
 text: "Main",
 childText: [
   {
    id: 3,
    text: "Child 1",
    childText: [
      {
        id: 5,
        text: "child 2"
        childText: [
        ....
        ]
      }
    ]
   }
 ]    
}
```

Any object can have `childText` any idea how to display this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821475/recursive-component-loading-with-recursive-array/38822751#38822751, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746516/use-component-in-itself/37747022#37747022, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707464/inject-parent-component-of-the-same-type-as-child-component/35707578#35707578

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a self-referencing component to do that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree-view',
  templateUrl: './tree-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-view.component.css']
})
export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() data: {children: Array<any>,name: string,id: number};
    showChildren: boolean;
}
```

In *tree-view.component.html*:

```
<ul class="office-list-unstyled" *ngIf="data">
  <li [ngClass]="{'office-parent': d.children.length && !showChildren,'office-child': d.children.length && showChildren}"
  *ngFor="let d of data.children">
    <span (click)="toggleOffices(d)">{{d.name}}</span>
    <app-tree-view *ngIf="d.children.length && showChildren" [data]="d"></app-tree-view>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that, *ngIf in the view is the thing to stop the loop.
And then you can use it in another component:

```
<app-tree-view [data]="offices"></app-tree-view>
```

**Offices** is your initial data for example.

Comment: What is inside `tree-view.component.html` ?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic Look at In the Html part of my answer.

Comment: How then I call that component from other component?